# retrieve a value entered in the input field of the schedule jqwidget dialog box with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jqwidget

I am trying to retrieve the values I enter in the input field of the scheduler dialog box with angular but I can't. Can someone help me with an example please? using console.log will be enough.

[image: img]

Comment: Which exact component are you using, can you show us your html and code behind of what you tried so far? Looking at their docs, which are genuinely bad, it seems like you may need to tap into the valueChange

Comment: Make sure you post in the actual question itself, you can edit your own questions

Comment: <jqxScheduler
  #scheduler
  [width]="getWidth()"
  [height]="600"
  [date]="date"
  [source]="dataAdapter"
  [showLegend]="true"
  (onAppointmentAdd)="AppointmentAdd($event)"
  [editDialogCreate]="editDialogCreate"
  [editDialogOpen]="editDialogOpen"
  [editDialogClose]="editDialogClose"
  [resources]="resources"
  [view]="'monthView'"
  [views]="views"
  [appointmentDataFields]="appointmentDataFields"
  [theme]="'black'"
>
</jqxScheduler>

Comment: Here is how I tried to retrieve an element from the field:  AppointmentAdd(item: any): void {
    console.log('event is:' +item.id);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am reading their docs correctly, your code of appointmentAdd should probably be like

```
AppointmentAdd(item: any) {
  let appointment = item.args;
  //tap into what appointment has.
}
```

As per their description, the event has one thing only

"This event is triggered when an appointment is added. event.args contains the event's arguments. This event has one argument: appointment - Object which has the appointmentDataFields. See appointmentDataFields property."

So whatever is defined in your appointmentDataFields is what you can tap into.

Comment: I tried the solution you gave me and this is what I get in the console: "event is:[object Object]". I can't get the exact value I enter in the field.

Comment: Right so the event itself is an object, you need to either cast it into something or tap into its properties. If you were to put a break point there was exactly is the object, what is its structure like?

Comment: AppointmentAdd(item: any) {
  let appointment = item.args;
  console.log(appointment.appointment.value)
}  "value" is a value of field. Thank you for your help. I used this code and it worked